# Converting logarithms between bases

Tags: logarithms

I saw very often that:

$$\log_{10}(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)}$$

So I assume it's true for every base:

$$\log_{a}(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)}$$

But, is the following statement true?

$$\log_{a}(x) = \frac{\log_n(x)}{\log_n(10)}$$

Where $n$ is an arbitrary non-zero real number.

Comment: No, this is not true. Just choose $n = 1$ or $a = 1$. Then $n$ and $a$ are non-zero real numbers. But $\dfrac{\log_n(x)}{\log_n(a)}$ would not be defined.

Comment: If the third expression would be true then combination with the (correct) second gives $\ln(a)=\log_n(10)$ which is of course not true for every $a$.

Comment: @drhab: But even the second is *not correct* for $a = 1$.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Agreed but OP says: "for every base". That can be interpreted as for every $a$ with $a>0$ and $a\neq1$.

Comment: You know that the final statement isn't true, because the left-hand side mentions $a$ and the right-hand side doesn't. Have you mistyped something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $a, n > 0$ and $a\neq 1$ indeed $$\log_a n = \frac{\ln n}{\ln a},$$

this is because $a^x = (e^{\ln a})^x = e^{x\cdot\ln a}$, so $x\cdot\ln a = \ln n$.
Yet, $e$ here isn't any special number except that $\ln e = 1$. Thus for any $b > 0$, $b\neq 1$
$$a^y = (b^{\log_b a})^y = e^{y\cdot\log_b a},$$
so $y\cdot\log_b a = \log_b n$. Also, using the first formula we can derive

$$\frac{\log_b n}{\log_b a} = \frac{\frac{\ln n}{\ln b}}{\frac{\ln a}{\ln b}} = \frac{\ln n \cdot \ln b}{\ln a \cdot\ln b} = \frac{\ln n}{\ln a} = \log_a n.$$

**Intuition:**

You can think intuitively of an logarithm as of *length* of a number (i.e., the number of digits in some base $b > 1$ representation). If your number is $$\underbrace{100\ldots00_b}_{k\text{ digits}}=b^k,$$ then precisely $k = \log_b n$.

Now, if you want to change base $b$ to $b^2$, then it's enough to "pair up" your digits,
because a base-$b$ $2$-digit number is equivalent to a base-$b^2$ $1$-digit number. Therefore, the length of your number in new units is 2 times shorter, only now each "digit" takes 2 units of space instead of just one.

$$\mathtt{156}_{10} = 
{\color{red}{\mathtt{1}}}{\color{darkred}{\mathtt{0}}}
{\color{blue}{\mathtt{0}}}{\color{darkblue}{\mathtt{1}}}
{\color{red}{\mathtt{1}}}{\color{darkred}{\mathtt{1}}}
{\color{blue}{\mathtt{0}}}{\color{darkblue}{\mathtt{0}}}_2 = 
({\color{red}{\mathtt{1}}}{\color{darkred}{\mathtt{0}}})
({\color{blue}{\mathtt{0}}}{\color{darkblue}{\mathtt{1}}})
({\color{red}{\mathtt{1}}}{\color{darkred}{\mathtt{0}}})
({\color{blue}{\mathtt{0}}}{\color{darkblue}{\mathtt{0}}}
)_{({\color{red}{2}}\times{\color{blue}{2}})} = 
{\color{red}{\mathtt{2}}}
{\color{blue}{\mathtt{1}}}
{\color{red}{\mathtt{3}}}
{\color{blue}{\mathtt{0}}}_4$$

In other words $\log_a n = \frac{\log_b n}{\log_b a}$ which is equivalent to $\log_b a = \frac{\log_b n}{\log_a n}$ means that ratio of base-$b$ length to base-$a$ length is equal to how long is $a$ in $b$. That is, if $a$ takes $3$ digits in base $b$, then $n$ takes $3$ times more base-$b$ digits than base-$a$ digits.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich You are correct, I've already fixed the issue, but was adding colors and that took a while.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is **not** true.

Choose $a = 1$. Then $\log_b(a) = 0$ for all $b > 0$ and $b \neq 1$. Therefore, $\log_a(x) = \dfrac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(a)}$ would not be defined.

Comment: "Choose $a=1$". But $\log_1(x)$ is not properly defined so $a=1$ is not a legal choice.

Comment: That's exactly the point why the statement is not true for *all* non-zero bases.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: "no".

The second expression is correct for any $a$ with $a>0$ and $a\neq1$.

Observe: if the third expression would be true then combination with the  second gives: $$\ln(a)=\log_n(10)$$ which is of course not true for every legal base $a$. The RHS is fixed, but the LHS is not fixed.

---

**edit** (to verify your *assumption* that the second expression is true)

The expression $\log_{a}x$ only makes sense if $x>0$, $a>0$ and
$a\neq1$.

It can be interpreted as the unique number that satisfies:

$$a^{\log_{a}x}=x$$ Special case $a=e$ gives: $$e^{\ln x}=x$$
Now observe that:

$$a^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}}=\left(e^{\ln a}\right)^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}}=e^{\ln a\times\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}}=e^{\ln x}=x$$

This allows us to conclude that: $$\log_{a}x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}$$